# How can someone corrupt an NTFS filesystem with a user space application

Tags: c#, ntfs, corruption

So the question may look strange. 
I've encountered many times a folder that cannot be deleted on a NTFS filesystem unless the PC was rebooted. When this happens, the issue is not a permission things, even the local administrator can't deal with it. But reboot the PC and the folder is gone.

Even this [Microsoft post](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/320081/you-cannot-delete-a-file-or-a-folder-on-an-ntfs-file-system-volume) says that it is a possible behaviour

Now, I have an application that creates a temporary folder, write inside it and deletes it afterward. Sometime, this application crashes because it cannot delete the files inside that folder. When I look at it, the temporary folder is empty and show the behaviour described above.

So my question goes as follow : How can my software do that? 
I would like to debug this but I have no clue where to start as I would expect the filesystem to be robust when accessed through the WinAPI. My application is a C# .Net 4.5 application.

Is there known vulnerabilities on the NTFS filesystems that could result in bad sectors? We're talking about Windows 7. This looks a lot like a race condition scenario.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm it's not locked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11060322/495455 or you could use a tool called Unlocker. The most likely reason is permissions. An admin can't delete a file/folder if someone else has a lock on it.

Comment: hmmm, no I can't confirm now. That may be a good potential solution. I will check

Comment: What error do you get when the code "crashes"?

Comment: I get a "System.UnauthorizedAccessException - Access to path <file_inside_temp_folder> is denied". Then I look at my temp folder, it's empty, but I cannot delete the folder.

Comment: If I am dealing with a locked file scenario, how come the temporary folder is being deleted after a reboot? Can the OS queue the delete operation? My windows under-the-hood knowledges isn't so good.

Comment: Can you post the code that deletes the file?

Comment: I can surely provide a simplified version of it tomorrow.

Comment: Some buggy antivirus software will keep a file locked after the application is done using it.  (The bug isn't because it opens the file -- AV has to do that -- but because it doesn't respond to the delete request by releasing all handles and approving the request)

Comment: Go and have a look at what processes have the file open [process-explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) if its you, then you have learned a very good lesson, if its your AV then you have learnt another

Comment: Maybe the failing app opened a file with FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE and crashed with the file open?